# Decode XML message in Java

Tags: java

i get the following String through a TCP connection:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
  <IOCMSG xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="AAA_XXX/IOCMSG.xsd">
    <FTRR>
     <TIME>20160302114115</TIME>
     <FPLA>
       <FCNADATA AIBT="" ARW="34R" ATL="" DATE="160302" DELO="FICUS" EOBT="201603020948" PORT="1234       " IDT="ARRIVO  " TCT="H" TXID="        "/></FPLA>
    </FTRR>
  </IOCMSG>
```

i need to extract from this string only the field inside the message.

i tried

```
DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
                    try {
                        parser.parse(new InputSource(new java.io.StringReader(fromAAI)));
                        Document doc = parser.getDocument();
                        String message = doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent();
                        System.out.println("___" + message);
                    } catch (SAXException e) {

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }
```

but of course it just print the TIME.
can anyone help me with some example?

Comment: Which message you want to print?

Comment: Why don't you take a look at what other methods than ``getTextContent()`` you can use?

Comment: all the String between quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use SAXParser than DOM.. It is event based and It will be very easy for you to get data between the tags.

[Sample Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)

Comment: the example says UTF-8 : File file = new File("c:\\file.xml"); but my input is a String, how can i adjust it?

Comment: @Daniele_r81: In that link the author tries to read from a xml file but in your case it is from string. use this code before you call the parse method, InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes()); . Now call saxParser.parse(is,handler)

Comment: i modified the File in : InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

Comment: yes it work, i just post the sample code i used. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate a XPath expression for this purpose:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new java.io.StringReader(fromAAI)));

XPath path = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "//TIME";

String time = (String) path.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

But a solution using StAX would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did and it work perfectly;

```
public class ReadXml {

    public ReadXml(String xmlString) {

        try {

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

                boolean bfpld = false;
                boolean bfpla = false;
                boolean bfplc = false;
                boolean btime = false;


                public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

                    if (qName.equals("FPLDDATA")) {

                        for (int i = 0 ; i < attributes.getLength() ; i++) {
                            new ShowMessage(attributes.getQName(i) + " VALUE:" + attributes.getValue(i));

                        bfpld = true;
                    }

                    if (qName.equals("FPLADATA")) {

                        for (int i = 0 ; i < attributes.getLength() ; i++) {
                            new ShowMessage(attributes.getQName(i) + " VALUE:" + attributes.getValue(i));

                        bfpla = true;
                    }

                    if (qName.equals("TIME")) {

                        btime = true;
                    }

                    if (qName.equals("FPLC")) {
                        for (int i = 0 ; i < attributes.getLength() ; i++) {
                            new ShowMessage(attributes.getQName(i) + " VALUE:" + attributes.getValue(i));
                        }

                        bfplc = true;
                    }
                }

                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

                    if (bfpld) {
                        new ShowMessage("FPLDDATA : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        bfpld = false;
                    }

                    if (bfpla) {
                        new ShowMessage("FPLADATA : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        bfpla = false;
                    }

                    if (btime) {
                        new ShowMessage("TIME : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        btime = false;
                    }

                    if (bfplc) {
                        new ShowMessage("FPLC : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        bfplc = false;
                    }

                }

            };

            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");
            InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
            is.setEncoding("UTF-8");

            saxParser.parse(is, handler);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

thanks a lot for your helps.